Run Time Anaysis of Nested Loop
Maybe a bit of a silly question but the run time analysis for this code is confusing me.
int i, j; 
int k = 0;

for(i = 1; i<= n; i*= 2){
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        k += (i+j);
    }
}

I understand that the outer loops runtime would be log(base2)n and that the overall value of the runtime is the runtime of the outer loop * the runtime of the inner loop. I'm just a little confused about the inner loop, I know the inner loop is iterating based on the value of i.
So would the inner loops runtime also be log(base2)n and then the overall runtime would be (log(base2)n)^2?
Somehow I don't feel like that's right.

Interesting to analyse while the code looks pre-K&R C.

The complexity analysis depends on whether the int type allows for arbitrary large integers (not just 64-bit).

The complexity in this case is determined by the number of times the inner loop will execute, multiplied by the complexity of body of the inner loop.
Regarding the number of times it will execute:
The outer loop will have the values 1,2,4,8,...,n.
In each of the outer loop iterations the inner loop will execute times according to this value.
Therefore altogether the inner loop will execute:
1+2+4+8+...+n.
This is a geometric series with a (first element) of 1, r (factor) of 2, and containing log(n) elements.
The formula for the sum of m elements of a geometric series is (r != 1):

Sm = a * (1 - r ^ (m+1)) / (1 - r)

If we assign a=1, r=2, m=log(n) we get:
1 * (1 - 2 ^ (logn+1)) / (1-2) =
1 * (1 - 2 * 2 ^ logn) / (1-2) =
1 * (1 - 2n)) / (-1) =
1 * (2n - 1) =
2*n - 1
=>
O(n)
In this specific case you can also see it as the value of a binary value of logn bits, all set to 1, which is again 2*n - 1 => O(n).
Regarding the body of the inner loop:
It contains a constant amount of calculations and so it is O(1).
=> Therefore the overall complexity is O(n) * O(1) = O(n).
Note:
This assumes that we are dealing with limited size integers (e.g. 64 bit), which is what types like int that you used usually are. If you want to include the analysis for arbitrary large integers up to n, representing and doing operations like addition (which you used) on them becomes O(logn) instead of O(1).

The code has two loops:
Outer Loop:

Starts with i=1 and multiplies i by 2 each time
Stops when i becomes larger than n
So, it runs log2(n) times (since multiplying by 2 repeatedly is the same as dividing n by 2 in reverse).

Inner Loop:

Runs from j=1 to j=i
The number of times it runs depends on the value of i
For example, if i=4, the inner loop runs 4 times

So

When i=1, the inner loop runs 1 time.
When i=2, the inner loop runs 2 times.
When i=4, the inner loop runs 4 times.
When i=8, the inner loop runs 8 times.

This continues until i reaches n.
total number of iterations of the inner loop is: 1+2+4+8+⋯+n
This means the inner loop runs
()
times in total when you add up all the work across the outer loop.
The runtime of the entire code is () because the inner loop dominates the total work done.

That makes sense as to why the inner loop is O(n) but I don't understand why in this case the inner loop would dominate the overall time complexity. If you changed the loops to be: for(i = 1; i<= n; i++){for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)} the overall time complexity would be n^2 not n. Does it have to do with the fact that j is incrementing based on i so when we get to the inner loop that means the outer loop has already been considered and we don't need to multiply them together?


the outer loops runtime would be log(base2)n

The code in the outer loop is run ldn times.

the overall [runtime] is the runtime of the outer loop * the runtime of the inner loop

The outer loop's runtime is the accumulated runtime of the inner loop, "plus change" for the outer loop's control.
Multiplying a boundary on the inner loop's runtime by the number of trips through the outer loop gives a like boundary on the inner loop's contribution to the outer loop's runtime.
For the inner loop, i is O(n), so its runtime is in O(n) (not log(base2)n: the addition is done for every j <= i <= n).
Multiplying this by the ldn trips through the outer loop gives a (valid!) upper bound on runtime growth with n:
it is in O(nlogn).
This does not mean a tighter bound can't be found – Gerard Haw's assessment of O(n) is perfectly valid.
